# How can I use Analyze API in spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Folks,

I want to perform - **GET /_analyze** to tokenize based on the analyzer using **spring-data-elasticsearch**

I see RequestConverters.analyze() in spring-data-elasticsearch. Hence I am able to do the following

```
AnalyzeRequest analyzeRequest = AnalyzeRequest.withGlobalAnalyzer("stop", payload);
        Request request = RequestConverters.analyze(analyzeRequest);
```

Above builds a Request but how do I make spring-data-elasticsearch call elastic search using the above Request?

I checked ElasticsearchRestTemplate and even RestHighLevelClient but none of the public methods in them take Request as parameter.

Any leads are much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you setup the `ElasticsearchOperations` with a `ElasticsearchRestTemplate`, you can do the following without the need to create a new client:

```
    AnalyzeRequest request = AnalyzeRequest.withGlobalAnalyzer("stop", "some text to analyse");
    ElasticsearchRestTemplate restTemplate = (ElasticsearchRestTemplate) this.operations;
    AnalyzeResponse analyzeResponse = restTemplate.execute(client -> client.indices().analyze(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as it might be helpful for someone else.

I did the following to get the tokens

```
     AnalyzeRequest analyzeRequest = AnalyzeRequest.withGlobalAnalyzer("stop", payload);
            AnalyzeResponse response = elasticSearchRestClientConfig.elasticsearchClient().indices().analyze(analyzeRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
  List<AnalyzeResponse.AnalyzeToken> tokens = response.getTokens();
```